# error Uncaught Error: Template parse errors when declared in app module

Tags: angular

Not sure what's going on and why this error popped up when I changed where it was being uploaded. Essentially I am changing a component from being only accessible in one component to the whole app and now I get that error.

### app.module.ts

```js
import { DefaultProfilePictureComponent } from '../sharedModules/components/default-profile-picture/default-profile-picture.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    DefaultProfilePictureComponent,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

### default-profile-picture.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-default-profile-picture',
  templateUrl: './default-profile-picture.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default-profile-picture.component.scss'],
})
export class DefaultProfilePictureComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() private lastNames: string;
  @Input() private big: boolean;
  @Input() private contactBox: boolean;

  private char1: string;
  private char2?: string;

  public constructor() {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.lastNames.split(' ').length);
    if (this.lastNames.split('').length > 1) {
      this.char1 = this.lastNames.split(' ')[0][0].toUpperCase();
      this.char2 = this.lastNames.split(' ')[1][0].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      this.char1 = this.lastNames.split(' ')[0][0].toUpperCase();
    }
  }
}
```

### default-profile-picture.component.html

```html
<div class="profile-container" *ngIf="big">
  <div class="profileImageBig">{{ char1 }} {{ char2 || '' }}</div>
</div>
```

### home.page.html

```html
<app-default-profile-picture
  *ngIf="!person.profilePicture"
  lastNames="person.lastNames"
  contactBox="true"
></app-default-profile-picture>
```

anywhere I try and use the component I get the error saying

> app-default-profile-picture' is not a known element:

but if I include it in the `home.page.module.ts` then I get the error saying that it is declared in two modules. What gives? Thanks!

Comment: are there two modules

Comment: I think you meant to use square brackets on your declaration `[lastNames]="person.lastNames"` and `[contactBox]="true"` for proper template binding

Comment: I have about 5 component that have their own module files (for example) `home.page.module.ts`, `dashboard.page.module.ts`, before the `DefaultProfilePictureComponent` was only being used in the `home.page.html` and that was fine, there were no error. but when I moved the `DefaultProfilePictureComponent` to the `app.module.ts` file that's when I started getting the various errors

Comment: @Dalorzo it doesn't matter as the error continues, with the brackets I was getting the error `lastNames` is not a known property of app-default-profile-picture

Comment: try exporting the component from the module in which it is declared. @NgModule({
  imports: ...,
  declarations: [..., DefaultProfilePictureComponent, ...],
  exports: [..., DefaultProfilePictureComponent]
}) This will make this component available to be used by other modules

Comment: @Gagan, still the same problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using it wrong.A component can be only by used in the module that you import it.For in your case the problem is you cannot load a component that is imported by a module in another module to allow it to use.export the component from the
home.page.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    DefaultProfilePictureComponent,
    ...
  ],
exports:[ DefaultProfilePictureComponent]
  ...
})
```

and import it in other module you want for examples in app.modules.ts

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports:[
BrwsrModule,
...,
HomePageModule
],


  ...
})
```

Comment: unfortunately using the method above I can only use the DefaultProfilePictureComponent in `home.page.html` and that's all

Comment: if you want to us it in others you can import the it to other modules as in app module.But i dont recommend this as a best practice.The best way is to create a shared Module,That is a separate module that is used by all other modules.And like You declared Default profile picture Earlier in Homepage Declare it in the shared module and export it and now import the shared module to the all the modules.this is the best way

Comment: well I created one for that and the issue persists. I am going to make a separate one.

Comment: same problem, same error says that it's not a known angular element[here is the new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327008/error-with-unknown-angular-element-using-a-shared-module)

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code,It look like you have created and registered this component in another module like shared Module.

If that is case then I will suggest you to import that shared Module in your app module and don't declare component inside app module ,just importing shared Module will do its work.