# Error with unknown angular element using a shared module

Tags: angular

Previously on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325465/error-uncaught-error-template-parse-errors-when-declared-in-app-module/58325743?noredirect=1#comment103011729_58325743)
I agree with the answer poster that the best way to handle this is to create a shared module. Which I have started to do, however the initial issue continues with a component not being known in angular

### shared.module.ts

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DefaultProfilePictureComponent } from './components/default-profile-picture/default-profile-picture.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [DefaultProfilePictureComponent],
  exports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, DefaultProfilePictureComponent, ReactiveFormsModule],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

however when trying to use the DefaultProfilePicture within the home.page.ts I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'lastNames' since it isn't a known property of 'app-default-profile-picture'.
1. If 'app-default-profile-picture' is an Angular component and it has 'lastNames' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-default-profile-picture' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
            <ion-col size="6" *ngIf="!userInfo.profilePicture">
              <app-default-profile-picture [ERROR ->][lastNames]="userInfo.lastNames" [big]="true"></app-default-profile-picture>
```

### app.module.ts

```js
import { SharedModule } from '../sharedModules/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [
    SharedModule
  ],
})
```

### home.page.ts

```js
import { SharedModule } from '../../sharedModules/shared.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  entryComponents: [NotificationComponent, ProfileComponent],
  declarations: [HomePage, ProfileComponent, NotificationComponent],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

### home.page.html

```html
<app-default-profile-picture [lastNames]="userInfo.lastNames" [big]="true"></app-default-profile-picture>
```

### default-profile-picture.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-default-profile-picture',
  templateUrl: './default-profile-picture.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default-profile-picture.component.scss'],
})
export class DefaultProfilePictureComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() private lastNames: string;
  @Input() private big: boolean;
  @Input() private contactBox: boolean;

  private char1: string;
  private char2?: string;

  public constructor() {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.lastNames.split(' ').length);
    if (this.lastNames.split('').length > 1) {
      this.char1 = this.lastNames.split(' ')[0][0].toUpperCase();
      this.char2 = this.lastNames.split(' ')[1][0].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      this.char1 = this.lastNames.split(' ')[0][0].toUpperCase();
    }
  }
}
```

### default-profile-picture.component.html

```html
<div *ngIf="!big && !contactBox">
  <div class="profileImage">{{ char1 }} {{ char2 }}</div>
</div>

<div class="profile-container" *ngIf="big">
  <div class="profileImageBig">{{ char1 }} {{ char2 || '' }}</div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="contactBox">
  <div class="contact-box ion-text-center">{{ char1 }} {{ char2 || '' }}</div>
</div>
```

anyone know the problem with this? Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to stop the application from running and load it again. It's been a long day. Sorry